# Show that $\big\{\{a\},\{a, b\}\big\} = \big\{\{c\},\{c, d\}\big\}$ if and only if $a = c$ and $b = d.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've done the “ if ” part in the question (as shown in the picture). But I don't know how to prove the “only if ” part.

That is show that

> $a = c$ and $b = d\;$ if $\;\big\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\big\} = \big\{\{c\},\{c,d\}\big\}$.

This is the picture of my proof about the “ if ” part.

[image: my proof]

Please tell me how do I do the “ only if ” part of the question.

Comment: In your proof, you write "But $b \neq c$ (proved above)."  However, that conclusion above was dependent on "If $\{a,b\} = \{c\}$", which is inconsistent with the condition in use for the quoted sentence, "If $\{a,b\} = \{c,d\}$".  You seem to have stretched the two cases "$\{a\} = \{c\}$ and $\{a,b\} = \{c,d\}$" and "$\{a\} = \{c,d\}$ and $\{a,b\} = \{c\}$" into four cases, creating both excess work and complicated dependencies among the four cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: if two sets are equal, in particular they have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

The image you posted actually tackles the "only if" part. There you reached the wrong conclusion that $b\neq c$. When "$P$ or $Q$" is true and you know $P$ to be true, it doesn't follow that $Q$ is false. However, from $\{a,b\}=\{c\}$ it follows that $a=c$ *and* $b=c$, not just "or"!

The "if" part is actually trivial: when $a=c$ and $b=d$ you can just replace any instance of $a$ by $c$ and any instance of $b$ by $d$, hence
$$
\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} = \{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$A$  If and only if $B$  means that , A implies B *and* B implies A .

In your case A is
$$
\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} = \{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}
$$

and B is $a=c$ and $
b=d$.

You have proven that A implies B (in the picture( with the corrections  mentioned by @cristoph that is you have to consider $b=c$ ) ) and B implies A is trivial .